# easy_install fails on error "Couldn't find setup script" after binary upload?

Tags: python, binary, easy-install, python-c-extension

After uploading a binary distribution of my Python C extension with `python setup.py bdist upload`, `easy_install [my-package-name]` fails on "error: Couldn't find a setup script in /tmp/easy_install/package-name-etc-etc".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 42):

This may not be related to your specific problem, but I am providing this information in case it is helpful to others.

I hit exactly this error when running `easy_install xyz`.  The problem turned out to be that I had a subdirectory named `xyz` in the current working directory and easy_install was expecting to find a setup script locally in that subdirectory instead of going out to the web to get the real `xyz`.  Renaming my local xyz directory temporarily fixed the problem.

This is one of a number of situations in which the command line argument you provide can be unintentionally shadowed by a file or folder of the same name. Another example is `make`: if you run `make test` in an attempt to make your test target and you happen to have a folder named `test` then `make` will not do what you want. The solution in that case is to indicate [Phony Targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html).

Comment: You don't even need to change the name of your directory. The fix is as simple as typing `cd ..` and trying easy_install again from a different cwd. I'd recommend testing this before looking at Martijn's answer, because it's an easy gotcha.

Comment: Wow, would have taken me a while to realize this on my own. Great answer.

Comment: "The problem turned out to be that I had a subdirectory named xyz in the current working directory" I think this is a kind of general problem.

Answer (score 8):

easy_install expects to find either a source distribution, or an egg. It's best to upload source distributions (`sdist`) to PyPI (or whatever distribution server you are using), and only upload eggs if your python package contains C extensions, and then only for Windows eggs (see my answer to [Can I create a single egg for multiple versions of python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136930/can-i-create-a-single-egg-for-multiple-versions-of-python/6225707#6225707)).

The `bdist` command, without additional configuration, creates a `.tar.gz` or `.zip` archive containing the compiled python files (and any C extensions compiled) for your current platform, sans installer (so not including the `setup.py` file). It's intended for unpacking by hand in your site-packages location and pre-dates distribution via eggs. If you were to unzip it, you'll notice it even included the full, absolute path to your site-packages directory in the tarball!

You can configure `bdist` to generate a RPM or a .deb file, or a simple Windows installer, but these are again aimed at providing installation bundles for other distribution systems not related to PyPI and easy_install.

So, to summarize, in most cases it's best to upload an `sdist` source distribution and have easy_install do the python compilation (into an egg) on installation.

If you do want to upload a pre-compiled distribution (which is then tied to specific Python version and the platform for which it was compiled), use the `bdist_egg` command instead.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you don't actually really intend to easy_install the 'directory', which will look for a setup.py file.
In simple words, you may be doing `easy_install xyz/`
while what you really want to do is `easy_install xyz`