# Can't install via pip because of egg_info error

Tags: django, windows, python-2.7, pip

No matter which package I'm trying to install, I get this error:

```
error: invalid command 'egg_info'

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in c:\users\zorpix\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-Zorpix\virtualenv
Storing complete log in C:\Users\Zorpix\pip\pip.log
```

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425106/python-pip-install-fails-invalid-command-egg-info), but the answer doesn't work for me. I can install the distribute package, which so far is the only package I can install, but it doesn't fix the problem, as the egg_info error returns as soon as I try to install another package. I'm getting pretty frustrated with this, as I can't find anything helpful anywhere. I've also had django and pip and everything installed before, but I had to reinstall it all, and now it's not working... Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the log it says it stored:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Python27\Scripts\pip-script.py run on 07/26/13 11:30:42
Downloading/unpacking virtualenv

  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/
  URLs to search for versions for virtualenv:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.3.tar.gz#md5=36b766604542f2c34d8dffdb21ba14a9 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.6.2.tar.gz#md5=e948af53ad41ca2718c4034484fcd694 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.6.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.7.tar.gz#md5=dcc105e5a3907a9dcaa978f813a4f526 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.7
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.3.2-py2.4.egg#md5=6913c03f02167fe4ac32add76c3edeb7 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.4.9.tar.gz#md5=c49067cab242b5ff8c7b681a5a99533a (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.4.9
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-0.8.tar.gz#md5=88c187a93a78c4c9bd54eef9ef0e0f03 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 0.8
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-0.9.1-py2.4.egg#md5=f595300f14597da25feabaececcf62a2 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.6.3.tar.gz#md5=73a69184e35f1e2c2f9016c889c4d26a (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.6.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-0.8.3.tar.gz#md5=d635fb7de359ff603a1fc395933724d1 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 0.8.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.8.3.tar.gz#md5=d42ab84b1b38258f2a57365841186f71 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.8.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.3.1.tar.gz#md5=e70ed86cc3823f0b622e80e035b59297 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.3.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.5.tar.gz#md5=a8c756de9661323b1f95311e79f8a5f3 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.5
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.3.4-py2.6.egg#md5=f5cf3d4dba3a224351fb5f90f59dae1a (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.3-py2.4.egg#md5=ff872f8b8dcb3dc76d9c2793afc9b1a5 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-0.8.3-py2.4.egg#md5=fbcb29d72e35ee93d80738d46e69d350 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.3.4-py2.5.egg#md5=2fd8f371cc83c2a49009e5fe51fcd9c9 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.0.tar.gz#md5=fb86aabdfc2033612b936cf08ad811ec (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.0
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-0.8.3-py2.5.egg#md5=7592e9dd19388a037768840caac00255 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.3.1-py2.5.egg#md5=f042320f7301a77311b876ed55d2a635 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.7.1.tar.gz#md5=1a07359ff6e5dbfaefa6381516293b47 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.7.1
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.3.3-py2.4.egg#md5=9cd8f513ba25e09be54ead5b1325ad3e (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.2-py2.5.egg#md5=0043570e1c16af8d3c9fa1e99bce012b (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.3.3.tar.gz#md5=28e2955aed4ffc4dc3df02dc632b5c42 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.3.3
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-0.8.1-py2.4.egg#md5=fa8831295f1073151876375c4567f5cd (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.7.1.1.tar.gz#md5=e06efff3c3dd5f88758dde29e108bfdd (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.7.1.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.4.tar.gz#md5=ef70dc53c648f4253335351c65b5740f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.4rc1.tar.gz#md5=fb62a93b054e877e6a6c92f7dcd0b6ae (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.4rc1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-0.8.4.tar.gz#md5=30f053782cc29363927b848263ae9158 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 0.8.4
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-0.9.2-py2.4.egg#md5=319b534ed28e2d31b124b1a76f42fbc7 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-0.9.2-py2.5.egg#md5=7a4d37d0c3f83f917d7a6556f31bb31d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-0.8.2-py2.5.egg#md5=eedbc037902cd2010b055451641addcf (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.3.2.tar.gz#md5=a013d5a7d9aeddc16bee88604d6de636 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.3.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-0.9.tar.gz#md5=17a52f8801cbeb6805f4a4650dc89468 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 0.9
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.0-py2.5.egg#md5=e6881a6353543b0af8b116ed8ed2f6f6 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-0.9.2.tar.gz#md5=78b6e73600db0d5ed8c0e507f0f7d705 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 0.9.2
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-0.8.1-py2.5.egg#md5=ad5869374196f7d533a9b649adfe9014 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.4.8.tar.gz#md5=74ded4025a56e538c1c8df6b9825a8b8 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.4.8
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-0.9.1.tar.gz#md5=d9abf1dc9dcaf603c60840c582414f66 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 0.9.1
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.3.4-py2.4.egg#md5=bd62418a72b7e09a637ef368b7b0101b (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.4.5.tar.gz#md5=d3c621dd9797789fef78442e336df63e (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.4.5
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.6.tar.gz#md5=b1c585e0bbe4fca56bfa0b34aff87bd9 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.6
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-0.8.2.tar.gz#md5=241f157e92dd9052b5a4b43efcef8035 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 0.8.2
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.3.1-py2.4.egg#md5=708cc5281dae7fdd8d996cdb55bef52d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-0.8.2-py2.4.egg#md5=4a92b99c93026031b7298906bf126ccd (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.4.1.tar.gz#md5=6ab218532376c2a389ef4ea030ff96f2 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.4.1
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.3.3-py2.5.egg#md5=fae350c941cd9eadf5e9a407c37a2e03 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.8.tar.gz#md5=fdab30066a1d731ca6fe22a4c23b9e80 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.8
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.3.4.tar.gz#md5=77d675df104b90fceec749150bd5014f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.3.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.4.2.tar.gz#md5=7b1a10f0e84dd945c9b006ace1e1bb16 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.4.2
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-0.8.4-py2.4.egg#md5=6d2db4c08a9b8a7b59e1ab7731791381 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-0.9-py2.4.egg#md5=12b34ae909f578910c293ecfe7c793e3 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.4.6.tar.gz#md5=f576969d591a054132fe8c9165c2b3c3 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.4.6
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-0.8.1.tar.gz#md5=5d7b4784f530bd8acf44b568776dbd3c (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 0.8.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.4.3.tar.gz#md5=2b639cee32d15fd049a49561957afe4b (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.4.3
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-0.8.4-py2.5.egg#md5=40300b786dad2e8380ef785c4998f421 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.0-py2.4.egg#md5=6199b281bf6e7370d896520eb3a968f8 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.2.tar.gz#md5=7ad454e52f025cad631d03331ade4aaf (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.2
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.2-py2.4.egg#md5=53ab95a286cc0382e503306bb0df9d49 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.5.2.tar.gz#md5=fbcefbd8520bb64bc24a560c6019a73c (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.5.2
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.1-py2.4.egg#md5=d9b0de14426957e30b2aa7015451aa43 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.4.7-py2.5.egg#md5=e1bb0e1cbc4e2df64dfdde6b0867ef29 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.8.2.tar.gz#md5=174ca075c6b1a42c685415692ec4ce2e (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.8.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.6.1.tar.gz#md5=1a475df2219457b6b4febb9fe595d915 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.6.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.5.1.tar.gz#md5=3daa1f449d5d2ee03099484cecb1c2b7 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.5.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.4.4.tar.gz#md5=94161ae1500cb3a8b003c0c394c9dbbd (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.4.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.4.7.tar.gz#md5=979a7adf8467df7df800a45debd2074f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.4.7
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.7.2.tar.gz#md5=b5d63b05373a4344ae099a68875aae78 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.7.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.8.4.tar.gz#md5=1c7e56a7f895b2e71558f96e365ee7a7 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.8.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.7.1.2.tar.gz#md5=3be8a014c27340f48b56465f9109d9fa (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.7.1.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.9.tar.gz#md5=e03b76752b8ce7eee67c6298414cac79 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.9
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.8.1.tar.gz#md5=3aebe32859aa4512e1e679834c10f7bf (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.8.1
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-0.9.1-py2.5.egg#md5=573b8bd74a7b9b207b5eede8db386953 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.1.tar.gz#md5=8931b66dbb799120583dd107aab2fa89 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.1
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.3-py2.5.egg#md5=8102d251e3f1caf709722679a737f454 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.1-py2.5.egg#md5=1db8cdd823739c79330a138327239551 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.6.4.tar.gz#md5=1072b66d53c24e019a8f1304ac9d9fc5 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.6.4
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.3.2-py2.5.egg#md5=f2cd2b10b8be8b57e74cb1830fc0b504 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-0.9-py2.5.egg#md5=7c8e85680f1ede0844a496513366d7a5 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/); unknown archive format: .egg
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.10.tar.gz#md5=9745c28256c70c76d36adb3767a00212 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.10
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.9.1.tar.gz#md5=07e09df0adfca0b2d487e39a4bf2270a (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version: 1.9.1
  Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.4rc1.tar.gz#md5=fb62a93b054e877e6a6c92f7dcd0b6ae (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), version 1.4rc1 is a pre-release (use --pre to allow).
  Using version 1.10 (newest of versions: 1.10, 1.9.1, 1.9, 1.8.4, 1.8.3, 1.8.2, 1.8.1, 1.8, 1.7.2, 1.7.1.2, 1.7.1.1, 1.7.1, 1.7, 1.6.4, 1.6.3, 1.6.2, 1.6.1, 1.6, 1.5.2, 1.5.1, 1.5, 1.4.9, 1.4.8, 1.4.7, 1.4.6, 1.4.5, 1.4.4, 1.4.3, 1.4.2, 1.4.1, 1.4, 1.3.4, 1.3.3, 1.3.2, 1.3.1, 1.3, 1.2, 1.1, 1.0, 0.9.2, 0.9.1, 0.9, 0.8.4, 0.8.3, 0.8.2, 0.8.1, 0.8)
  Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.10.tar.gz#md5=9745c28256c70c76d36adb3767a00212 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package virtualenv

    C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'entry_points'

      warnings.warn(msg)

    C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'zip_safe'

      warnings.warn(msg)

    C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'test_suite'

      warnings.warn(msg)

    C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'tests_require'

      warnings.warn(msg)

    usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]

       or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]

       or: -c --help-commands

       or: -c cmd --help



    error: invalid command 'egg_info'

    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

    C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'entry_points'

  warnings.warn(msg)

C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'zip_safe'

  warnings.warn(msg)

C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'test_suite'

  warnings.warn(msg)

C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'tests_require'

  warnings.warn(msg)

usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]

   or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]

   or: -c --help-commands

   or: -c cmd --help



error: invalid command 'egg_info'

----------------------------------------

Cleaning up...

  Removing temporary dir c:\users\joey\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-Joey...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in c:\users\joey\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-Joey\virtualenv

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 134, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 236, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1124, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 257, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 670, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in c:\users\joey\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-Joey\virtualenv
```

**EDIT**:
Not sure what I did, but now I'm getting this error:

```
ImportError: No module named setuptools.command

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in c:\users\joey\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-Joey\Django
Storing complete log in C:\Users\Joey\pip\pip.log
```

What is this setuptools that I'm missing?

Comment: You tried the comment suggestions to the linked question as well?

Comment: you mean the other answer? Yes I tried that too... No dice

Comment: Try installing `python-dev, libpython-dev, libevent-dev` as `sudo`:

`sudo apt-get install python-dev` and the other ones. And now you are able to install via `pip`

Comment: isnt sudo a linux command? also, apt-get returns:

The term 'apt-get' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spe
lling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:8
+ apt-get <<<<  install python-dev
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (apt-get:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Have you installed: Distribute https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute/0.6#installation-instructions ?

Comment: Yes. I said so in the original question.

Comment: i had a similar problem, here is the answer to the related (duplicate ?) question : http://stackoverflow.com/a/42803623/880128

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Found out what was wrong. I never installed the setuptools for python, so it was missing some vital files, like the egg ones.

If you find yourself having my issue above, download [this file](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py) and then in powershell or command prompt, navigate to ez_setup’s directory and execute the command and this will run the file for you:

```
$ [sudo] python ez_setup.py
```

If you still need to install pip at this point, run:

```
$ [sudo] easy_install pip
```

easy_install was part of the setuptools, and therefore wouldn't work for installing pip.

Then, pip will successfully install django with the command:

```
$ [sudo] pip install django
```

Hope I saved someone the headache I gave myself!

~Zorpix

Comment: +1 for your answer. i had this problem on ubuntu 12.04 LTS. after installing `python-pip` via `apt-get` and then installing `virtualenv` via `pip`, I got the error "Command Python setup.py .... error code 1" while trying `sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper`. installing setuptools via ez_setup.py solved the problem :)

Comment: Glad my answer could be of help!

Comment: or maybe upgrade setuptools ``$ sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools``

Comment: didn't work for me sadly, had better luck with:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400370/easy-install-and-pip-broke-pkg-resources-distributionnotfound-distribute-0-6

Comment: Make sure you're version of setuptools is up to date using `pip show setuptools` It seems possible to have multiple conflicting installs of setuptools. This could possibly be because I use conda to manage packages with the anaconda distribution and using `import setuptools; setuptools.__version__` was showing '12.0.5' but this was still failing.  This was because the version the pip CLI was picking up was 0.6rc11

Comment: Fails for me: `error: Couldn't find a setup script in ez_setup.py`

Comment: maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178664/easy-install-fails-on-error-couldnt-find-setup-script-after-binary-upload

Comment: `ez_setup.py` can also found in pypi(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#unix-wget). In order to run `ez_setup.py`, just run `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | python`. If you are not using linux, follow given instructions in given link.

Comment: Note: now it's deprecated. When run it prints - `ez_setup.py is deprecated and when using it setuptools will be pinned to 33.1.1 since it's the last version that supports setuptools self upgrade/installation, check https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/581 for more info; use pip to install setuptools`

Answer (score 42):

**Try these:**
`pip install --upgrade setuptools` or `easy_install -U setuptools`

Comment: For python egg related errors, try to upgrade setuptools first line of defense. Thanks to stack user "Randall Ma" for sharing this solution in first place :)

Comment: just upgrading the setup tools isn't enough, still get the same error

Comment: It fails for me after this `   Uninstalling setuptools-1.1.6:
Exception`

Answer (score 10):

For me reinstalling and then upgrading the pip worked.

1. Reinstall pip by using below command or following link [How do I install pip on macOS or OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/installing-pip-on-mac-os-x)

   curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o - | python
2. Upgrade pip after it's installed

   pip install -U pip

Comment: just updating pip (py -m pip install --upgrade pip) did the trick for me.

Answer (score 7):

See this :
What Python version can I use with Django?¶
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/faq/install/

if you are using python27 you must to set django version :

try: $pip install django==1.9

Answer (score 6):

Having the same error trying to install matplotlib for Python 3, those solutions didn't work for me. It was just a matter of dependencies, though it wasn't clear in the error message.

I used `sudo apt-get build-dep python3-matplotlib` then `sudo pip3 install matplotlib` and it worked.

Hope it'll help !

Answer (score 4):

In my case this error message appeared because the package I was trying to install (storm) was not supported for Python 3.

Answer (score 4):

I'll add this in here as my problem had something todo with my `virtualenv`:

I hadn't activated my virtual environment and was trying to install my requirements, this ultimately led to my install failing and throwing this error message.

So ***make sure you activate your virtualenv!***

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to install pyautogui and followed instructions from the first answer but was unsuccessful. The difference for me was running `pip install pillow` and then running `pip install pyautogui`

I don't know what this means, but I hope this helps some people out.

Comment: This was very helpful! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

virtualenv is a tool to create isolated Python environments.

you will need to add the following to fix command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1, so inside your requirements.txt add this:

virtualenv==12.0.7

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to uninstall pip and reinstall it. So I could install my specific version.

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove python-pip
sudo easy_install pip
```