# Problems installing pip

Tags: python, pip, installation

Please can you help me install pip? I previously had pip but somehow I broke it and I tried uninstalling python and reinstalling it but I still cannot get pip back...

```
sudo python get-pip.py
```

> The directory '/Users/Name/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
>   The directory '/Users/Name/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
>   Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

```
sudo -H python get-pip.py
```

> Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

I also tried this:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/bin/easy_install-2.7", line 7, in 
>       from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2927, in 
>       @_call_aside
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
>       f(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2940, in _initialize_master_working_set
>       working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 637, in _build_master
>       return cls._build_from_requirements(**requires**)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 650, in _build_from_requirements
>       dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 829, in resolve
>       raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
>   pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'setuptools==1.1.6' distribution was not found and is required by the application

Then I found that `pip` is installed with python, but for some reason pip is not working.

```
brew install python
```

> Warning: python 2.7.13 is already installed

```
pip install regex
```

> zsh: command not found: pip

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

> zsh: command not found: pip

When I go here > `cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages && ls`
I find **distribute-0.6.14-py2.7.egg** and **pip-9.0.1.dist-info**

But when I go to `/usr/local/bin` I cannot find pip, only pip3:

I did try out some solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400370/easy-install-and-pip-broke-pkg-resources-distributionnotfound-distribute-0-6) but they are not working.

EDIT:

Following from the comment I tried

`sudo pip install regex
Password:
sudo: pip: command not found
➜  ~ python -m pip install regex
Collecting regex
  Downloading regex-2017.06.23.tar.gz (607kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 614kB 694kB/s 
Building wheels for collected packages: regex
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for regex ... done
  Stored in directory: /Users/Manal/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/aa/48/61/f321b8a521167213da5de2a65e76530e362e58e328b1d74ab3
Successfully built regex
Installing collected packages: regex
Successfully installed regex-2017.6.23`

I'm not sure why it worked? How can I use pip normally?

EDIT:

Something broke I think..

`➜  ~ pip install regex
zsh: command not found: pip
➜  ~ 
➜  ~ python -m pip install regex
Requirement already satisfied: regex in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
➜  ~ which pip
pip not found`

I dont know why which pip isnt returning anything?

EDIT:

Tried installing setup tools

`➜  ~ sudo brew install python-setuptools
Password:
Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all
build scripts full access to your system.
➜  ~ 
➜  ~ brew install python-setuptools 
Error: No available formula with the name "python-setuptools" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
➜  ~ 
➜  ~ sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
sudo: apt-get: command not found
➜  ~ 
➜  ~ easy_install -U setuptools
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install-2.7", line 7, in 
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/init.py", line 2927, in 
    @_call_aside
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/init.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/init.py", line 2940, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/init.py", line 637, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(requires)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/init.py", line 650, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/init.py", line 829, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'setuptools==1.1.6' distribution was not found and is required by the application`

Comment: do `sudo pip install regex` to install or try `python  -m pip install regex`

Comment: @Stack Please see the Edit. python -m pip install regex seems to work, how can I use pip normally?

Comment: `python -m pip install regex` worked because the `-m` is for `module` and `pip` is also a module, its an alternative way.

Comment: i think `pip` is not working normally because it is not in path, just add the directory where `pip` is present to the path.

Comment: you can find the directory where `pip` is installed by this command `which pip` and add it to the path variable by : `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/pip_dir`

Comment: which pip returns, //anaconda/bin/pip is that a little messed up? because i'm using homebrew

Comment: doesnt matter, try adding that to `PATH`

Comment: Ok I added the path but there is still an issue when i try to install other packages

Comment: Or maybe this isnt an issue with pip? Maybe i made a mistake with installing tensorflow

Comment: @Stack I dont know what happened but which pip doesnt return anything now.. please see my edit above

Comment: open the terminal in your root directory and type `which pip`

Comment: pip not found, it only works when I do python -m pip install regex

Comment: When i check this directory there is pip: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip.. but this directory is not returned when I type which pip. Which python returns /usr/local/bin/python

Comment: when you do `which pip` change your directory to `usr/local/` and try

Comment: ➜  ~ cd /usr/local 
➜  local which pip
pip not found

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools` , then do `sudo easy_install pip`

Comment: I'm using a mac. shall I just use brew instead of apt-get?

Comment: yes try that, if it doest work try apt-get

Comment: @Stack sorry it doesnt seem to be working, I dont know how I got into this mess :(. Please see edit above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148240/discussion-between-stack-and-reguser).

Comment: https://crossbar.io/docs/Installation-on-Mac-OS-X/