# Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to do `make install`, but I keep getting an error. I already tried following this answer: [Can't install via pip because of egg_info error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886647/cant-install-via-pip-because-of-egg-info-error)

```
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /abc/abc_env/build/MySQL-python
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/Pat/.pip/pip.log
```

the full debug log: http://pastebin.com/cnGgWU4G

Here’s the Makefile:

```
virtualenv-2.7 my_env && \
source my_env/bin/activate && \
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

It looks like the problem only happens in the virtual environment. I am able to do `pip install mysql-python` without a problem, but `pip install -r requirements.txt` has errors when trying to install `mysql-python`

requirements.txt below:

```
Flask==0.10.1
Jinja2==2.7.1
MarkupSafe==0.18
MySQL-python==1.2.4
PyYAML==3.10
SQLAlchemy==0.8.3
Tempita==0.5.1
Werkzeug==0.9.4
argparse==1.2.1
dataset==0.3.13
decorator==3.4.0
docopt==0.4.0
itsdangerous==0.23
mandrill==1.0.53
mysql-connector-python==1.0.12
requests==2.0.1
sqlalchemy-migrate==0.7.2
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There were several problems with the original code.

First, `MySQL-python` version `1.2.4` for some reason fails to install. Changing this to `1.2.5` fixes that error.

Second, `argparse` cannot be installed as is. It needs `--allow-all-external`. The new Makefile is below:

```
virtualenv-2.7 my_env && \
source my_env/bin/activate && \
pip install -r requirements.txt --allow-all-external
```

Third, `mysql-connector-python` version `1.0.12` doesn’t exist. Changing it to `1.1.4` worked.

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

If above answer do not do the trick. Try the following.

1. Install the MySQL. (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/)
2. Add the path. export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin

Now, run pip install -r requirements.txt