# command python setup.py egg_info failed

Tags: python

I keep getting the errors "pg_config executable not found" and "Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1" when trying to run pip install -r inside a virtual environment. I have done everything that has been suggested on other questions, including running `pip install --upgrade setuptools`, `easy_install -U setuptools` and `pip install --upgrade Distribute`. Is there anything else that can fix this error? The only people getting this error, for my group, are the two of us who are on Windows. Those who are on Mac OS aren't getting this error, only those of us who are on Windows. Screenshot here: http://tinypic.com/r/2drtd38/8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command python setup.py egg\_info failed with error code 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21517051/command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1)

Answer (score 0):

The Gohlke precompiled binaries are usually an easier way to install packages on windows:

[psycopg](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#psycopg)