# python setup.py egg_info failed with error 1

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install the python module 'tagg' using pip. But I'm getting the below error.

```
Collecting tagg
  Using cached tagg-0.1.2.tar.gz
Collecting Pygments==2.0.2 (from tagg)
  Using cached Pygments-2.0.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting argparse==1.2.1 (from tagg)
  Using cached argparse-1.2.1.tar.gz
Collecting prompt-toolkit==0.31 (from tagg)
  Using cached prompt_toolkit-0.31.tar.gz
Collecting six==1.9.0 (from tagg)
  Using cached six-1.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wcwidth==0.1.4 (from tagg)
  Using cached wcwidth-0.1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wsgiref==0.1.2 (from tagg)
  Using cached wsgiref-0.1.2.zip
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-nnpqo0do/wsgiref/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        import ez_setup
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>

      File "/tmp/pip-build-nnpqo0do/wsgiref/setup.py", line 5, in <module>

        import ez_setup

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-nnpqo0do/wsgiref
```

I have tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886647/cant-install-via-pip-because-of-egg-info-error). But its not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Download tagg-0.12.tar.gz from [**here**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tagg/0.1.2)
2. Extract the files to a folder
3. Open cmd and cd to the folder you extracted your files (you have to navigate to the folder where your setup.py is. It does not work from any other path)
4. Run command - python setup.py install