# DjangoCMS failed to create a project

Tags: python, pip, django-cms

I'm on Windows system and following [Install Django CMS tutorial](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/support-3.0.x/introduction/install.html). According to it I set up fresh virtual environment with Python 3.4.3, installed Djangocms-installer with pip and run command

> `(env) PS D:\Skyro\Documents\djangocms-project\sites> djangocms -p . mysite`

When I answered installer's questions, I got output with error message:

> `Creating the project
>   Please wait while I install dependencies
>   Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Roman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-0v8y2934\django-select2-py3`

I don't understand what is wrong and will be happy if you explain me what does it mean and how to fix it.

### My installing process from the beginning:

1. install Python 3.4.3 with default path and all options enabled.
2. `pip install --upgrade pip` (6.0.8 -> 6.1.1)
3. `pip install --upgrade setuptools` (12.0.5 -> 15.1)
4. `pip install virtualenv`
5. move to work folder and run `virtualenv env`
6. activate virtual environment with `.\env\Scripts\activate`
7. `pip install djangocms-installer`
8. create and move to empty folder 'sites'
9. `djangocms -p . mysite`
10. answer installer's questions
11. get error message

Maybe I should install Django too, but for now installing Django (1.8 or 1.7) doesn't resolve this error.

Comment: You seem to have issue with your setup tools.
Try this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17890155/4834035)

Comment: @VinayKaranam I have no problems with installing django, djangocms or other packages via pip. I also upgraded setuptools via pip. But I tried solution from your link and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it's a problem with current django-select2-py3 package.
Official django-select2 it's on a good way to handle python 3 too, but no official package has been released yet.
Which version of the installer are you using and which options have you chosen in the installer wizard?

Comment: I added to the post all steps I made that led me to this error.

Comment: This is something that needs to be addressed in djangocms-link (test it against latest select2 develop branch and change dependencies according to it); djangocms installer / django CMS can't do much for third party failures. I can suggest to user filer plugins (**-f** option) or using python2

Comment: djangocms-link should be fixed now