# error installing MySQL-python with pip

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am having following error when I try to run server

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 
Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

I tried using `pip install mysql-python`, but it gave me this errror:

```
Collecting mysql-python Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-t81ezx2d/mysql-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
    from setup_posix import get_config
  File "/tmp/pip-build-t81ezx2d/mysql-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'    
----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-t81ezx2d/mysql-python
```

These are the modules I have installed through pip:

```
alabaster==0.7.6
Babel==2.0
Django==1.8.3
docutils==0.12
Jinja2==2.8
MarkupSafe==0.23
mysql-connector-python==2.0.4
Pygments==2.0.2
pytz==2015.4
six==1.9.0
snowballstemmer==1.2.0
Sphinx==1.3.1
sphinx-rtd-theme==0.1.8
```

Any help?

Edit: solved the issue using [mysqlclient](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python), Mysql-python isn't available for Python 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886647/cant-install-via-pip-because-of-egg-info-error ?

Answer (score 2):

first install then it will work fine.
`apt-get install python-dev libmysqlclient-dev`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a capitalization issue?

try this:

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

Hopefully that works, but if not, try using

```
pip search stringToSearchFor
```

to find the proper package name

Comment: Could be this issue due to the fact that I am using python3?