# TensorFlow installation on Ubuntu

Tags: installation, machine-learning, tensorflow

When I try to install TensorFlow Machine Learning library on Ubunto (vmware image) using command :

```
$ pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

after downloading the package I got this error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 14, in 
>       IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-GgS7fR-build/setup.py'
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 14, in
>
> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   '/tmp/pip-GgS7fR-build/setup.py'

I am using pip, python 2.7 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS vmware image

Can anyone please help me to solve this error?

full `pip.log` file error :

```sh
------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/bin/pip run on Sun Nov 22 06:06:30 2015
Downloading/unpacking https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
  Downloading from URL https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-GgS7fR-build/setup.py'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-GgS7fR-build/setup.py'

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 126, in main
    self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 223, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 980, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 216, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 255, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode))
InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Ubuntu 14.04 in VMware and use the same command.

Comment: Does this help? "Found out what was wrong. I never installed the setuptools for python, so it was missing some vital files, like the egg ones." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886647/cant-install-via-pip-because-of-egg-info-error

Comment: "i had this problem on ubuntu 12.04 LTS. after installing python-pip via apt-get and then installing virtualenv via pip, I got the error "Command Python setup.py .... error code 1""

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) i did try on 14.04 but again error on vmware :( but tensor flow easy installed on Ubunto 14.04 machine (no vmware environment)