# How can I use Conda to install MySQLdb?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I've read several different explanation regarding how to install MySQLdb, but I'm not sure which case applies to me since my error message is different.  My system can't seem to find MySQLdb. I installed pymysql, but i need to import MySQLdb to use procedures from that library.

Thanks for your help.

---

```
$ conda install MySQLdb
```

Fetching package metadata: ....
Error: No packages found in current osx-64 channels matching: mysqldb

Did you mean one of these?

```
pymysql
```

You can search for this package on anaconda.org with

```
anaconda search -t conda mysqldb

$ anaconda search -t conda mysqldb
```

Using anaconda-server api site https://api.anaconda.org
Run 'anaconda show ' to get more details:
No packages found
     Name                      |  Version | Package Types   | Platforms
     ------------------------- |   ------ | --------------- | ---------------
Found 0 packages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since early 2018, the [mysql](https://anaconda.org/search?q=mysql) package has become available from the [conda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/mysql/files) and [anaconda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/mysql) channels. The former is often more up-to-date and, as of April 2021, provides version 8 compared to the latter's version 5.

Install using

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge mysql
```

Comment: I tried that, but I receive this message:
---

Error: No packages found in current osx-64 channels matching: mysql-python

Did you mean one of these?

    mysql-connector-python

You can search for this package on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda mysql-python

Comment: Have you tried `conda install binstar`, and then `binstar search -t conda mysql-python`? Or `pip install mysql-python`?

Comment: when i run the pip command I receive this error:

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-Kt0Nb_/mysql-python

Comment: Try `conda install pip`. Here's more on what could help with your setup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886647/cant-install-via-pip-because-of-egg-info-error

Comment: I receive a similar error (thanks for all your help):
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-ubayrP/mysql-python

Comment: Take a look at the link I included with my previous comment. There's a few ways to fix the conventional installation pipes, depending on what exactly got missing during original anaconda setup.

Comment: I ran that file and followed the other instructions. It ran successfully but I still get a similar error message when I try to install mysql-python.

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/p1/xg17tts541n1__p_srg1n2j80000gn/T/pip-build-EThMFm/mysql-python

Comment: Did you also `pip install --upgrade setuptools` or `easy_install -U setuptools`?

Comment: I did.  What is going on??

Comment: I think something worked.   I reran 
    binstar search -t conda mysql-python 
I several user packages are listed.  What should I try next?  See output :
     Name                      |  Version | Package Types   | Platforms      
     ------------------------- |   ------ | --------------- | ---------------
     alefnula/mysql-python     |    1.2.5 | conda           | osx-64         
                                          : Python interface to MySQL
     anaconda/mysql-python     |    1.2.5 | conda           | linux-64, win-32, linux-32
                                         
....

Comment: Did you also check for the `binstar` packages? These can be installed using `conda` so you wouldn't have to deal with the `pip` issues.

Comment: Yes something worked with Binstar. for instance this is listed: 
alefnula/mysql-python     |    1.2.5 | conda           | osx-64         
But im not sure what to do with it.

Comment: This worked apparently:
   conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/derickl mysql-python

Comment: But what is the relationship between mysql-python and MySQLdb?  Im trying to execute code that imports MySQLdb.

Comment: `python-mysql` is the python interface to MySQL. Here are docs: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html. Just scroll down to the examples.

Comment: Thanks again for all your time. That was very generous.

Comment: Happy to help, updated my answer to condense the thread or anyone coming by later.

Answer (score 29):

Try to use this command:

```
conda install mysql-python
```

Comment: tested it works on ubuntu 14.04 the easiest solution!

Comment: Tested it. Works on windows too

Comment: Only works on Python 2.7. On Python3, do ```pip install mysqlclient```.

Comment: I do `pip install mysqlclient`, and it worked on Anaconda3 + Python3.7 + Windows10 environment

Answer (score 16):

For those Googlers in 2018+, you can install from the [bioconda channel](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/mysqlclient)

```
conda install -c bioconda mysqlclient
```

Comment: For Windows the following should work:
`conda install -c josh mysqlclient`

From here: https://anaconda.org/josh/mysqlclient

Comment: Worked for me on MacOS, as of July 2018

Comment: @BrenBarn Worked for me on Windows :)

Comment: For conda nubes (e.g. myself) run this after activating your conda virtual env to have it applied there.

Answer (score 3):

To install this package with conda run:

```
conda install -c anaconda mysql-python=1.2.5
```

check here:
https://anaconda.org/anaconda/mysql-python

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
conda install mysql-connector-python
```

Comment: Note this is a different library!  I.e this is the official one from Oralce, which is written in pure python vs the C extension based MySQLDb.  Supposedly MySQLDb (aka mysqlclient) may dramatically out perform this (depending upon on the use context).

Answer (score 1):

~/anaconda2$ conda install mysql-python

works on ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.8 should execute the following command

```
conda install -c anaconda mysql-connector-python
```

Answer (score 0):

For Anaconda Python, @StephenRauch has the correct solution, as it is officially supported in the Anaconda Enterprise documentation:

```
conda install -c anaconda mysql-connector-python
```

Reference: https://enterprise-docs.anaconda.com/en/latest/data-science-workflows/data/mysql.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this for mysqldb with python above 3.x

```
pip install mysqlclient
```