# How to install MySQLdb for Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, mysql-python

I tried `conda install -c anaconda mysql-connector-python` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55479673/1601703) but after installing it I tried to run `import MySQLdb as db` buy it give me error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-08dd46cbf704> in <module>
      1 ## package used to connect the database
----> 2 import MySQLdb as db
      3 import pandas as pd
      4 import numpy as np
      5 import warnings

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

How I can install MySQLdb for Anaconda?

Comment: Are you sure mysql-connector-python is the package that contains mysqldb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `MySQLdb`, you have to install `mysql-python` for Python 2:

```
conda install -c anaconda mysql-python
```

`mysqlclient` is the recommended library to use moving forward for Python 2 and 3:

```
conda install -c anaconda mysqlclient
```

Here's what Django recommends for mysql libraries https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers

Comment: How that command is different from `conda install mysqlclient`? I just did it and it installed MySQLdb

Comment: `mysqlclient` should be good too but `mysql-connector-python` as specified in your question won't give you `MySQLdb`.

Comment: So for Python 3 best option is `mysqlclient`? Also what is the difference between `conda install -c mysqlclient` and `conda install mysqlclient` and which one is preferable?

Comment: Why u change from `conda` to `anaconda` in install command? Why it is better?

Comment: `-c` is used to install a package from a specific channel. For your case, `anaconda` is the name of the channel. You can still install a package without specifying the channel. See documentation at https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html

Answer (score 0):

As per [mysqldb's pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/MySQL-python/#description), you need to install mysqldb as

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

In summary: you installed the wrong python library and the correct way is:

```
conda install -c anaconda mysql-python
```

Comment: How that command is different from `conda install mysqlclient`? I just did it and it installed MySQLdb

Comment: No, it installed a different python library that can connect to mysql.

Comment: Should I uninstall `mysqlclient` before running `conda install -c anaconda mysql-python`?

Comment: Am I understand correctly that `mysqlclient` is a fork for python 3 and `mysql-python` is only for python 2?