# python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install **pystashop** module.
I have a Python 3.4 installed on Windows 7 64 bits.

When I try pip install pystashop I get this error:

```
Collecting pystashop
Downloading pystashop-0.4.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-zyt3yyca\pystashop\setup.py", line 12, in <module>
    execfile(os.path.join('pystashop', 'version.py'))
NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-zyt3yyca\pystashop
```

how can I solve this?

**ADD:**

I tryed to install and run 'python ez_setup.py' and after run 'easy_install pip' but with no success. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install via pip because of egg\_info error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886647/cant-install-via-pip-because-of-egg-info-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`execfile` is a [standard library builtin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile) in Python 2. It was [removed](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins) in Python 3, which means that **pystashop** does not support Python 3. You should try [contacting the developer(s)](https://github.com/openlabs/pystashop/issues) and request Python 3 support, and in the meantime see if you can get by with Python 2.

You can attempt to remedy the situation yourself by cloning the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/openlabs/pystashop), making changes, and installing with `python3 setup.py install`, but there's no guarantee that it will work properly. The offending code seems to be [here](https://github.com/openlabs/pystashop/blob/develop/setup.py#L12):

```
execfile(os.path.join('pystashop', 'version.py'))
```

You can replace this with the following:

```
exec(open(os.path.join('pystashop','version.py')).read())
```

This will provide the expected functionality. From a cursory glance over the code, everything else *appears* to be compatible with Python 3, though I may have missed something.