# How to fix ‘“ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:” when trying to install desktop Library using pip?

Tags: python, libraries

I am revisiting the python language and I am experiencing difficulty setting up my environment. 
I am using - python 3.8.2 (packaged with the system) - robotframework-desktoplibrary 1.0.1  - pip 20.2.3
I encounter an error message when attempting to install desktop library via pip. I believe the error is caused by pip attempting to install in python 3.8 folders (without sufficient permissions) instead of the python 3 folder. 
I encounter the following error message when attempting to install robotframework-desktoplibrary via pip:

```
Collecting robotframework-desktoplibrary
  Using cached robotframework-desktoplibrary-1.0.1.zip (15.6 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\shivendra.singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\shivendra.singh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kcqq2ihh\\robotframework-desktoplibrary\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\shivendra.singh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kcqq2ihh\\robotframework-desktoplibrary\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\shivendra.singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-bisto_oa'
         cwd: C:\Users\shivendra.singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kcqq2ihh\robotframework-desktoplibrary\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\shivendra.singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kcqq2ihh\robotframework-desktoplibrary\setup.py", line 4, in <module>
        execfile(join(dirname(abspath(__file__)), 'target', 'src', 'SikuliLibrary', 'version.py'))
    NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Why do you believe that, and if so, how exactly are you running `pip`? Similar questions seem to be about attempting to install old Python 2 librhries on Python 3.

Comment: Please include the command that generated this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python setup.py egg\_info failed with error code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34332453/python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1)