# How to fix this error "egg_info failed ......" error in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have be getting the following error message while trying to download packages in python 3.4.3 with pip

```
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in C:\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-vm7h4kaq\cx-oracle
```

I have been getting this error message very often, I am unable to download many packages because of this. Someone please help me to fix this and also explain what this message means.

Comment: Check this link to see if it helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886647/cant-install-via-pip-because-of-egg-info-error

Comment: @Rao, did not get any help from that link.