# Egg_info error when installing rpy2 windows 10

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I want to install `rpy2` and next install `anaconda` with `spyder` to use python.

I tried this command

```
py -m pip install rpy2
```

but it gave me this error

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-o27u4aog\rpy2\
```

I tried to install `unroll` as well with similar pip command and it gave me similar error

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-nyfqo09i\uroll\
```

Like suggested for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886647/cant-install-via-pip-because-of-egg-info-error) I succesfully did

```
py -m pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

and

```
py -m pip install ez_setup
```

but nothing helped. I had to unistall `anaconda` to `--upgrade setuptools` looking foward to install `rpy2` but now I dont know what to do more.

I am using windows 10, `R 3.2.5` and `python 3.5.`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use precompiled binaries.

See: http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/default/overview.html#microsoft-s-windows-precompiled-binaries

The main page for rpy2 will be updated to indicate that `pip install` is not the easiest way to install rpy2 on Windows.