# Issue installing Keras with Tensorflow backend on Anaconda

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, anaconda, keras

I am trying to install keras, theano and tensorflow on Anaconda.
Following are the steps I have followed:
Step 1:
Created an environment 'nnet'

```
conda create -nnnet python=3.5 anaconda
```

Step 2:

```
activate nnet
```

Step 3:
Installing Spyder on the new environment

```
conda install spyder
```

Step 4:
Installing the packages

```
pip install theano
pip install tensorflow
pip install keras
```

Step 5:
update all packages

```
conda update --all
```

Step 6:
run spyder in nnet environment

Now when I run my code which tries to import keras, I get this error:

> ImportError:  Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed. 
>   Most likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy. If
>   you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes
>   all files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
>
> Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be
>   found.

Then I uninstalled numpy and reinstalled. However the error still persists.

Also upon checking the packages installed in anaconda navigator under nnet environment, I see tensorflow and theano missing.
[Here is the list I am referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCGFF.png)

I have used these steps before and have successfully used these packages before.(Imported and used in code) 
However, I am unable to figure out the issue now. Any sort of help or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by modifying the commands in step 4:

Step 4:

```
conda install -c anaconda theano 
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow 
conda install -c conda-forge keras
```

The packages now work fine and I can import them too.