# pip install web.py but errors modulenotfounderror

Tags: python

use pip to install web.py,but it errors:

```
C:\Users\apple>pip install web.py
Collecting web.py
  Downloading web.py-0.38.tar.gz (91kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 537kB/s
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\apple\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-   drp6zgow\web.py\setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    from web import __version__
      File "C:\Users\apple\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-drp6zgow\web.py\web\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    import utils, db, net, wsgi, http, webapi, httpserver, debugerror
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in    
C:\Users\apple\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-drp6zgow\web.py\
```

Could you give me the reason and the steps, on how to solve it?

Comment: you need to do `pip install utils`

Comment: see this link , it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886647/cant-install-via-pip-because-of-egg-info-error

Comment: when I pip install utils, I pip install web.py again, but it errors:                                                  File    "c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\db\__init__.py", line 69
        print "var", var
                  ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

            ----------------------------------------
        Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\apple\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-tusoviu1\web.py\

Comment: I pip install utils, pip install web.py again, it error:                                         File "c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\db\__init__.py", line 69
        print "var", var
                  ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\apple\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-tusoviu1\web.py\

Answer (score 2):

Have a try with the following

```
pip2 install web.py
```