# Having trouble with install ldap with python

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, ldap

I used the following command and it did not fix it. `pip install python-ldap`

It gave me the following error.

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Dwayne\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-tgslpxii\python-ldap\
```

I did try to fix it with the following commands. For installing `pystan`, `flexget` and  `pylint` but it didnt resolve the situation at hand.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/python-pip-install-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886647/cant-install-via-pip-because-of-egg-info-error

Comment: @lit I have tried all of that answers but none worked

Comment: Which version of Python, `python --version`, and which version of pip, `pip --version`? See also https://github.com/donnemartin/gitsome/issues/4

Comment: @lit Im using pip version 9.0.1 and python 3.6.1