# pip install zipline fails on Windows 10

Tags: python, installation, pip, windows-10, zipline

I can't install `zipline` on `Windows 10` with `Python 3.6`.
I tried it with `Pycharm` and the `terminal`, both fail with this error message:

`Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-x6gaykzm\zipline\`

I have also tried `pip3 install --upgrade setuptools`, `pip install ez_setup` and `pip install ez_setup` like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886647/cant-install-via-pip-because-of-egg-info-error) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/python-pip-install-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-c)

I have also installed `numpy 1.13.0 + mkl`

Can anybody help on this topic? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python pip install gives "Command "python setup.py egg\_info" failed with error code 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/python-pip-install-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing Visual Studio C++ Build Tools and restarting the computer I could install zipline. I don't know which of the facts causes it.

Answer (score 1):

Good to know that you figured out the cause.

The reason for your problem was that the zipline doesn't support python 3.5 or above for now, but it does support python 3.4. and python 3.4 makes use of Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express(http://microsoft-visual-cpp-express.soft32.com/) and this is what python 3.4 is compatible with.

So it makes the zipline users a must have package in order to use zipline.