# python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1

Tags: python, installation, pip

I'm running Ubuntu 17.04 (fresh install) and already installed pip. However, when I try to install anything I get this:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   /tmp/pip-build-kBfUEp/kivy/

Depending on what I'm installing, I get the same thing but slighty different. For example:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   /tmp/pip-build-zqj5Ka/pypiwin32/

I've tried everything and I have absolute no idea how to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install via pip because of egg\_info error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886647/cant-install-via-pip-because-of-egg-info-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same error, I used the following code to get out of this error:
(I was working on centOS 7)

1) sudo yum install MySQL-devel

2) sudo yum install openssl - devel

3) sudo yum install python-devel

I hope this works for you.