# Error while installing Tensorflow on mac

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow

I have Python 3.5.4 running with Anaconda. I am getting the following error while installing Tensorflow on mac by using

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.4.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

It has something to do with numpy package, I guess

> Error: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/_q/wmhj5hgn1_97ld78v29tky340000gn/T/pip-build-fo1po1/numpy/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install via pip because of egg\_info error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886647/cant-install-via-pip-because-of-egg-info-error)

Comment: hey man, could you up vote or select my answer as preferred if I answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo easy_install numpy` Then reinstall TensorFlow. I hope this helps you.